# Gradient of a composition of functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble forumulating the gradient of a composition of functions:

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, $r:(a,b)\to \mathbb R^n$

Now I know this will be an n dimensional vector, now I'm under the impression that I can use the chain rule for this ie with $\partial f$ denoting the Jacobian matrix of f.

ie$\nabla f(r(t)) = \partial f(r(t))\partial r(t) = \partial f(r(t))\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$ I know this cant be right as the dimensions dont match. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, which dimensions don’t match?

Comment: but one doesn't write $\partial f$ for the gradient of $f$

Comment: For a scalar valued function, $\partial f=\nabla f$.

Comment: @Loobear23 then $\partial f=\nabla f={\rm grad}\ f$ with your convention

Comment: But using my method the gradient would be a scalar?

Comment: what I did answer, here below, gives you a scalar

Comment: Yes and gradient should be an n dimensional vector here.

Comment: but NOT for the composition you had set

Answer (score 1):

You have for $f\circ r(t)$ the chain rule 
$(f\circ r)'(t)=f'(r(t))\cdot r'(t)$, that is, in classical symbols
$$\frac{df\circ r(t)}{dt}={\rm grad}f(r(t))\frac{dr(t)}{dt},
$$
or unfolding it
$$\frac{d(f\circ r)}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}\frac{dx^1}{dt}+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}\frac{dx^n}{dt},
$$
and on taking evaluations
$$\frac{d(f\circ r)}{dt}|_{t_0}=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}|_{r(t_0)}\frac{dx^1}{dt}|_{t_0}+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}|_{r(t_0)}\frac{dx^n}{dt}|_{t_0}
.$$

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the gradient isnt the derivative, I understand this is how you take the derivatve.

Comment: because the composition $(a,b)\to\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is simple a map $(a,b)\to\mathbb R$

Comment: thanks man for the confidence

Comment: You're answering a different question to what I asked, I didnt ask how to calculate the derivative I asked how to calculate the gradient...

Comment: the gradient of $f$ is a row that has the derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$, which other gradient do you want to calculate?